# What are the order types of all the total orders on $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: order-theory, ordinals

Two ordered sets have the same order type if there exists an order-preserving bijection between them whose inverse is also order-preserving.  My question is, what are the order types of all the total orders on the set of natural numbers.

Can you start with all the countable ordinals, as well as the order type of the rational numbers, and then construct all the order types using order type addition, order type  multiplication, and the [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(order_theory)) operation?  Or is there some total order on $\mathbb{N}$ whose order type cannot be constructed in this way?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer, but classifying total orders on $\mathbb N$ is the same as classifying countable total orders (since we don't use any structure on $\mathbb N$ except the set itself).

Now, any countable total order is order-isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb Q$ with its natural order. A proof can be found [here](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/higher_math_online/section05.06.html).

Comment: I said "Can you start with all the countable ordinals, **as well as the order type of the rational numbers**, and then construct all the order types using order type addition, order type multiplication, and the dual operation?"  So the starting point already includes one dense total order.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Indeed, I missed that.

Comment: So now do you think the answer to my second question is yes or no?

Comment: While  correct, I don't think this answers the question of what order types are possible.  Clearly every countable ordinal is, but we can put in descending chains as well.

Answer (score 1):

[It seems to me that the order type of $\mathbb{Q} \sqcup 2 \sqcup \mathbb{Q} \sqcup 2 \sqcup ...$ does not fall in this category.] **edit:** as you pointed out, it does on the contrary. In fact, only $\aleph_1$ many order types can be constructed using your conditions, "while" there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ countable linear order types.

Indeed, for each binary sequence $u: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0;1\}$, consider the transfinite sum $L_u= \sum \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} Q_{u(n)}$ where $Q_1= \mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{Z}$ and $Q_0 = 2$. I would say that $L_u$ can be constructed using your rules iff $u$ is eventually periodic, but a proof would require a bit of care. Perhaps a form of "pumping lemma" would apply here.

Comment: Isn't the order type you're describing just $(\rho+2)\omega$ where $\rho$ is the order type of the rational numbers?

Comment: Indeed! However, using non eventually periodic binary sequences will yield order types outside of your "rational category".

Comment: What do you mean by a total order generated by a binary sequence?

Comment: I added more information, but so far this is not a proof (at least without HC).

Comment: Why couldn't you make $Q_1=\mathbb{Z}$ and $Q_0=1$, wouldn't that make things simpler?  Also, assuming your example is valid, what if I added "countable sum" to my list of operations, then would it suffice to produce all the order types?

Comment: I just started thinking with $\mathbb{Q}$ in mind to avoid ordinals, but your way is better. Adding countable sums definitely changes things and impairs my cardinality argument, but I don't know about the anwser. It seems that then there are still countable products of linear orders, and then countable towers of exponentiation exponentiation, and then higher order operations... But the more you add, the harder it gets to see what would fall outside of the category. Perhaps taking a look at the book *Linear orderings* of Rosenstein would help.