# What is the cardinality of the set of equivalence classes of countable order types under bi-embeddability?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Two ordered sets have the same order type if there exists an order isomorphism between them.  Now the set $X$ of all order types of countable totally ordered sets has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2943677/71829).  But I'd like to find the cardinality of a smaller set.

Let us define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ as follows.  If $a$ is the order type of $A$ and $b$ is the order type of $B$, then we say that $a\sim b$ if there exists an order isomorphism between $A$ and a subset of $B$, and an order isomorphism between $B$ and a subset of $A$.  My question is, what is the cardinality of the set of equivalence classes of elements of $X$ under this equivalence relation?

Is it still $2^{\aleph_0}$, or is it smaller than that?

Comment: Well, there are definitely still $\aleph_1$ different equivalence classes (the countable ordinals), so you can't prove in ZFC that there are less than $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Either an answer showing that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ equivalence classes, or an answer showing that there are $\aleph_1$ equivalence classes, would satisfy me.

Comment: @EricWofsey I guess the question is whether the number of equivalence classes is (in ZFC) provably equal to $\aleph_1$, or provably equal to $\mathfrak c$, or neither.

Comment: Nice question. A small remark: The order of the rationals is *universal* in the sense that any countable linear order embeds into it. An order is *scattered* if and only if it contains no copy of $\mathbb Q$. Clearly, you can limit your attention to scattered orders. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38626/462) answer (and the references given there) is now relevant: in particular, you cannot have infinite families of incomparable orders (under embeddability).

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Silly question: under AD, can there be a well-quasi-order which surjects onto $\mathbb{R}$? If not, that plus Laver's theorem, the AD-version of Burgess' theorem, and the fact that $V$ and $L(\mathbb{R})$ agree about this question shows that the answer is $\omega_1$ assuming large cardinals ... :P (But seriously, I don't see how to cook up a "really long" wqo under AD.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Your linked answer is relevant to another question of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2936721/71829 Can you post an answer to that question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cardinality is $\aleph_1$.

As noted by Andrés Caicedo, the nonscattered countable linear orders form a single $\sim$-class, so it suffices to explain why there are only $\aleph_1$-many $\sim$-classes of scattered types.

Rich Laver proved that the embeddability quasiorder of (countable) nonscattered types is a well-quasiorder. Call this quasiorder $W$. Let $P=W/\sim$ be the quotient poset. The poset $P$ has no infinite antichains or infinite properly descending chains. The task is to determine the size of $P$.

Recursively partition $P$ into levels: $L_0$ is the antichain of minimal elements of $P$, and for each $\alpha>0$, define $L_{\alpha}$ to be the antichain of minimal elements of $P-\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} L_{\beta}$. Let $\gamma$ be the least ordinal that does not index any level. Then $|P| = |\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma} L_{\alpha}| = |\gamma|$, since $\gamma$ is infinite and the levels are finite and partition $P$.

The question asks for the number of $\sim$-classes, which is the cardinality of $P$. We have just shown that this is $|\gamma|$. By Eric Wofsey's comment, $|\gamma|\geq \aleph_1$. 
To obtain a contradiction, assume that $|\gamma|>\aleph_1$. Choose an ordinal $\delta$ so that $\aleph_1<\delta<\gamma$. Level $L_{\delta}$ is not empty, since $\delta<\gamma$, so pick a countable linear order $\Lambda_{\delta}$ so that $(\Lambda_{\delta}/\sim)\in L_{\delta}$. Every level $L_{\varepsilon}$, for $\varepsilon <\delta$, contains some $\Lambda_{\varepsilon}/\sim$, where $\Lambda_{\varepsilon}$ is a countable linear order embeddable in $\Lambda_{\delta}$. (If there exists some $\varepsilon < \delta$ whose level $L_{\varepsilon}$ does not contain the $\sim$-class of any poset embeddable in $\Lambda_{\delta}$, then the least-indexed level with this property would have to contain $\Lambda_{\delta}/\sim$, contradicting either $\varepsilon <\delta$ or the disjointness of the levels.)

But now we have a countable linear order $\Lambda_{\delta}$ which has $|\delta|$-many order types of pairwise $\sim$-inequivalent, countable linear orders that are embeddable into it, namely the $\Lambda_{\varepsilon}$'s. And remember that $\delta$ is uncountable. We have now obtained a contradiction to 
Fraisse's Second Conjecture (also proved by Laver), which states that a countable scattered linear order has only countably many $\sim$-types of suborders.   \\\\\

You will find the statements of all four of Fraisse's Conjectures on page 178 of Rosenstein's book *Linear Orderings*, Academic Press, 1982. The proof (due to Laver) of Fraisse's Second Conjecture is Theorem 10.52 of this book.