# Regarding the "smallest" nontrivial, dense order type.

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, order-theory

1. Is $\eta$, the order type of the rationals, necessarily the smallest nontrivial, dense order type?

By "smallest" I mean that there is no dense order which embeds into $\eta$, into which $\eta$ does not embed. Note that the left/right/total closure of $\eta$ will also have this property, so $\eta$ won't be unique in this regard; what matters is whether or not there can be a dense order *strictly smaller* than $\eta$.

Obviously, the smallest dense order is $0$ (because "$(\forall x,y\in\emptyset)(\exists z\in\emptyset)(x<z<y)$" holds vacuously), and any finite order type larger than $0$ is sparse. I just want to be sure that every smaller [nontrivial] order type is *necessarily* sparse, and that there isn't some bizarre order type $\tau$ which is provably dense, and which provably embeds into $\eta$, for which "$\eta$ embeds into $\tau$" cannot be proven.

2. Is the non-existence of a dense order type $\kappa$, such that $\eta<\kappa<\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the order type of the reals, such that $\kappa$ is *not* the sum of countably-many copies of $\eta$ (or closures thereof), equivalent to the continuum hypothesis?

I suspect that there may be dense, countable order types into which $\eta$ embeds which do not embed into $\eta$. However, I imagine that every such order type is of the form $\sum_{i\in\varphi_\flat(\omega_{0^\star}^{\spadesuit})}\eta_i$, where each $\eta_i$ is either $\eta$ itself or a closure of $\eta$, and $\varphi_\flat(\omega_{0^\star}^\spadesuit)$ is "some stupid-large countable ordinal." So it stands to reason that if there are any other dense orders between $\eta$ and $\lambda$ they must be inaccessible from below. The only way I can see this happening is if $\kappa$ contains more than countably many points, but fewer than continuum many points - which is the negation of the continuum hypothesis. But there might be some other way to get dense orders $<\lambda$ besides pasting together copies of $\eta$, in which case there might still be countable, dense order types which are strictly larger than $\eta$ independently of CH. Intuitively, I would think the exclusion of sums is equivalent to the non-existence of $\kappa$ with the same number of limit points ($2$) as $\eta$ and $\lambda$. If this is the case, it might be easier to show equivalence with CH.

Comment: It is a theorem of Cantor that there is a unique countable dense linear order without endpoints, up to isomorphism, which should help here. It is not clear to me what $<$ means in $\eta<\kappa<\lambda$.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti $\alpha<\beta$ means $\alpha$ embeds into $\beta$ and $\beta$ does not embed into $\alpha$. This seemed like the most natural way to compare order types beyond well-orders.

Comment: Why on earth would you use notation like "$\varphi_\flat(\omega_{0^\star}^\spadesuit)$"? What possible purpose does that serve?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Because the notation for large ordinals can already be quite silly, and I thought it was funny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to see that $\eta$ embeds into any nontrivial dense linear order $J$ (of any cardinality whatsoever), at least assuming the axiom of choice: we can just use a "greedy algorithm" to embed $\eta$ into $J$ by well-ordering the elements of $\eta$ and sending the $i$th rational in this well-ordering to some element of $J$ which "fits the pattern so far" (this is where density of $J$ is used). In more detail, let $\eta=\{q_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$, let $J=\{\alpha_\mu: \mu\in\kappa\}$, and recursively define a map $F:\eta\rightarrow J$ by sending $q_i$ to $\alpha_\mu$ where $\mu$ is the least element of $\kappa$ satisfying $$\forall j<i[F(q_j)<\alpha_\mu\iff q_j<q_i].$$ The existence, for each $i$, of such a $\mu$ uses the density of $J$.

*(Actually, technically there's a gap here: we need to assume that $J$ has no endpoints. But we can do this WLOG: just remove any endpoints that $J$ may have before starting the construction!)*

In fact, this same argument shows that every countable linear order whatsoever embeds into $\eta$. To give a bit more detail, given a countable linear order $L=\{l_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$, we recursively define an embedding $F:L\rightarrow\eta$ by setting $F(l_i)$ to be the lexicographically-least rational $q$ satisfying $$\forall j<i[l_j<_Ll_i\iff F(l_j)<q].$$ The existence of such a $q$ at each stage is where density of $\eta$ (+ absence of endpoints) is used. Note that this is only *half* of a "back-and-forth" argument; building *isomorphisms*, rather than just *embeddings*, in related situations often require thinking about both directions simultaneously.

Putting everything together, this means that **any two countable dense nontrivial linear orders are bi-embeddable**. It's worth noting that bi-embeddability is a *much* coarser relation than isomorphism; for example, there are continuum-many scattered (= do not contain a copy of $\eta$) countable linear orders up to isomorphism, but only $\aleph_1$-many up to bi-embeddability, and it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\aleph_1<\mathfrak{c}$. See [this old MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947505/what-is-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-equivalence-classes-of-countable-order-typ).

(And the axiom of choice is necessary here, since in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone there may be nontrivial dense sets of reals which are incomparable with $\eta$ with respect to embeddability; this happens in Cohen's original model of $\mathsf{ZF+\neg AC}$, for instance.)

Comment: Was the first formula supposed to be "$\ldots<\alpha_\mu\iff q_j<q_i\ldots$"?

Comment: @R.Burton Indeed, fixed!

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of overlap between my answer and Noah's, but I'm posting it anyway, because addresses your second question and  contains some additional points about your first question.

A few comments first:

(a) The empty linear order is not the only finite dense linear order: the one-element linear order is also dense. This is because "density" means $\forall x\forall x\, (x<y\to \exists z\, x < z < z)$. This axiom is satisfied in the one-element linear order, since there are no $x$ and $y$ with $x < y$ in this order. However, it is true that any dense linear order with at least *two* elements is infinite.

(b) Disregarding these two finite dense linear orders, let's write $\leq$ for the embeddability preorder on the class of infinite dense linear orders, i.e., $L\leq L'$ iff $L$ embeds in $L'$. Like any preorder, $\leq$ induces an equivalence relation $\sim$, by $L\sim L'$ iff $L\leq L'$ and $L'\leq L$.

Then you write:

> By "smallest" I mean that there is no dense order which embeds into $\eta$, into which $\eta$ does not embed.

i.e., for all $L$, if $L\leq \eta$, then $\eta \leq L$ (and hence $\eta\sim L$). This notion should be called "minimal". The term "smallest" or "minimum" usually means: for all $L$, $\eta \leq L$. Note that this is a stronger sense of "smallest": a minimum element of a preorder is automatically a minimal element, but not conversely.

(c) You write "I suspect that there may be dense, countable order types into which $\eta$ embeds which do not embed into $\eta$." No, in fact *every* countable linear order $L$ embeds in $\eta$. (There is no hypothesis on $L$ other than countability, i.e., $L$ need not be dense, and $\eta$ need not embed in $L$.) This is a simple "forth" argument: Enumerate $L$ as $(a_i)_{i\in \omega}$ and build a function $L\to \eta$ by recursion, mapping each new element to an element of $\eta$ that sits in the correct place relative to the images of the previous elements.

---

Now to address your questions.

(1) In fact, $\eta$, the order type of the rationals, is not just minimal (i.e., "smallest" in your sense), it is actually smallest in the stronger sense mentioned above.

*Proof*: Let $L$ be an infinite dense linear order. Removing the endpoints (if $L$ has a greatest or least element), we obtain $L'$, an infinite dense linear order without endpoints. By [Löwenheim-Skolem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem), $L'$ has a countably infinite elementary substructure $L''$, which is again a dense linear order without endpoints. By [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_isomorphism_theorem), $L''$ is isomorphic to $\eta$. This isomorphism gives an embedding $\eta\to L$, so $\eta \leq L$.

(2) By the discussion above, there is definitely no countable "intermediate order type" $\kappa$. So your stipulation "such that $\kappa$ is *not* the sum of countably-many copies of $\eta$ (or closures thereof)" is unnecessary, since any such countable union of countable orders will be countable, and hence equivalent to $\eta$. But there are intermediate order types of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

In [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/131947/2126) by Joel David Hamkins, a construction is given of a dense set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ such that there is no non-identity order-preserving map $A\to A$. It follows that there is no embedding $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to A$, since the restriction $f|_A\colon A\to A$ would be a non-identity order preserving map.

Thus, we can prove (without assuming CH) that there is an order type $\kappa$ (the order type of the set $A$) such that $\eta < \kappa < \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the order type of $\mathbb{R}$. We have $\eta\leq \kappa$ by (1) since $\kappa$ is dense, but $\kappa\not\leq\eta$ because of its cardinality. And we have $\kappa\leq \lambda$ since $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, but $\lambda\not\leq\kappa$ as shown above.

Comment: By 'closures' are meant the three order types obtained by adding to $\eta$ one or two endpoints.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Oh, I see, thanks! I'll edit.

Comment: If you just want an uncountable order type below $\lambda$ any uncountable totally imperfect subset of $\mathbb R$ will do. For if a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ has order type $\ge\lambda$ then some subset $B$ of $A$ is the range of a strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, so $B$ is an uncountable $G_\delta$ set, so it contains a nonempty perfect set.